# I want my app to support only xlarge screens with mdpi density

Tags: android, screen, android-manifest, resolution, mdpi

I'm developing an app that only supports tablets for now.
But I don't have high res photos for tablets with higher density (Like latest Asus tablet with ~230 dpi, 1920X1200, I think it's called TF700T or something like this), and I don't want to start testing the ui on this screen.
I have only mdpi photos for most of the general tablets today (1280x720 and 10.1'), and I developed the app on a tablet with this screen, which is the common size of tablets today.

I know how to set the app to support only xlarge screens, but I also want it to support only mdpi screens. I couldn't figure out a way for doing it from Android Developers guides.

My manifest for now:

```
<supports-screens 
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
      android:largeScreens="false"
      android:normalScreens="false"
      android:smallScreens="false"/>
```

Thanks,
Elad

Comment: Define support. What do you expect users to see on the 7" or 5" tablet or a high density screen phone like the Galaxy S III? The usage of supports-screens is generally for screen compatibility mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<compatible-screens>`:

```
<compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
```

See: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html

Though creating an app that is highly resolution-dependent like this is not a particularly good strategy.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I probably have missed this. I know this is in a good strategy, but this is only the first release :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent **mdpi** density tablets from installing your application, but you can force them to run it in [**screen compatibility mode**](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html) , that is done with `android:largestWidthLimitDp` attribute of `<support-screens>`

Also there's the attribute `android:compatibleWidthLimitDp` that will offer the user to choose if he wants to run the app in screen compat mode or not.

For the description and use of those two attributes read [**here**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#compatibleWidth)

Comment: I don't want to prevent them, I want that only mdpi density tablets will be able to use the app.